# Why does lvm2 use mixed case UUIDs?

Tags: lvm, uuid, standard

I noticed that `lvm2` objects use mixed case UUIDs:

```
~ # lvdisplay                                                                                                                                        
  (...)
  LV UUID                yD0FAx-1nHj-O8vV-qNyI-k1RA-hZsj-UF439H


~ # pvdisplay                                                                                                                                        
  (...)
  PV UUID               mXOay3-gT0A-3eVM-5nVD-RI2q-D6A9-j2o04v
```

Is there a particular reason for that, taken into account that [the standard (see 6.5.4)](https://www.itu.int/rec/T-REC-X.667-201210-I/en) explicitly discourages such a use (emphasis mine)?

> NOTE – It is recommended that the hexadecimal representation used in
>   all human-readable formats be **restricted to lower-case letters**.
>   Software processing this representation is, however, required to
>   accept both upper and lower case letters as specified in 6.5.2.

Answer (score 1):

X.667 discusses UUIDs represented in hexadecimal; LVM UUIDs aren’t. In addition, case is significant in LVM UUIDs:

```
lvdisplay select uuid=yD0FAx-1nHj-O8vV-qNyI-k1RA-hZsj-UF439H
```

will find your LV, but

```
lvdisplay select uuid=YD0FAx-1nHj-O8vV-qNyI-k1RA-hZsj-UF439H
```

won’t.

Answer (score 1):

It should be historical. 32 byte UUIDs date back to LVM 1.

[Digging through old sources](ftp://sources.redhat.com/pub/lvm/) reveals that at some point it was changed from 16 to 32 bytes:

```
lvm-0.8final-2.4.0.patch:312:-#define   UUID_LEN        32  /* don't change!!! */
lvm-0.8final-2.4.0.patch:313:+#define   UUID_LEN        16  /* don't change!!! */
```

[Digging through the mailing list](https://www.redhat.com/archives/linux-lvm/index.html) yields some old discussions about UUIDs in early LVM:

https://www.redhat.com/archives/linux-lvm/1999-August/msg00076.html

```
> It should be
> able to identify PVs by UUID (if this is in 0.7,

Today it identifies PVs by  PV number/VG name  pair.
That obviously is not unique ;*)
But it's sufficient on a single computer system.
```

https://www.redhat.com/archives/linux-lvm/1999-November/msg00039.html

```
One of my TODO items for the future still is to have UUIDs
(Uniform Unique Identifiers) for VGs and for system ownership of a VG.
```

https://www.redhat.com/archives/linux-lvm/2000-September/msg00043.html

```
I hope nobody is calling pvcreate in an rc script...  From what Heinz
said about LVM 0.9, it will finally implement UUID support, so LVM
will be able to identify a PV no matter what device it is on.
```

The oldest reference I found for the 32 byte type of UUID dates to November/December 2000:

https://www.redhat.com/archives/linux-lvm/2000-December/msg00185.html

```
Subject: [linux-lvm] LVM-0.9 Touble in pvcreate
[...]
PV UUID               MB5eIp-jxvc-4pup-ncSM-O6xT-fMmu-JjYgzM
```

So it should have been added (as visible to frontend) in LVM 0.9.

But even so, I could no find exact reasoning mentioned for it. And I guess nobody saw any reason to change it to a more "standard" UUID format ever since.

Actually I found one complaint about it in LVM2 code:

https://github.com/lvmteam/lvm2/blob/32a8865a272d31d5bc12332a4da0309ce3af9243/lib/uuid/uuid.c#L115-L119

```
/*
 * The only validity check we have is that
 * the uuid just contains characters from
 * '_c'.  A checksum would have been nice :(
 */
```

Can't have everything, I guess. :-)